# Checking for response header for status - HTTP Status Codes

Tags: php

I have a piece of code that updates  shopify product via API and it updates without any problems. The issue is that I am trying to check for the header status response and I can get it right.

print_r for $modified_product['headers'] returns the following

Array ( [status] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK [Date] => Tue, 28 Apr 2020 08:30:03 GMT [Content-Type] => application/json; charset=utf-8 [Transfer-Encoding] => chunked [Connection] => keep-alive)

I will really appreciate any help/advice.

```
$modified_product = shopify_call($token, $shop, "/admin/products/" . $product_id . ".json", $modify_data, 'PUT');

// Storage response
$status = $modified_product['headers']['status'];

//echo $status;      (This prints = HTTP/1.1 200 OK)

//print_r($modified_product['headers']);

if ($status == "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" ) {  // Somehow this compare does not work. I always get problem
    echo "Done";
}else
{
   echo "Problem";  
}
```

Comment: Use `var_dump` instead of `print_r` to more clearly see what exactly is in those strings; perhaps the trailing newline is included or other whitespace.

Comment: var_dump give this

array(38) { ["status"]=> string(16) "HTTP/1.1 200 OK " ["Date"]=> string(29) "Tue, 28 Apr 2020 08:44:59 GMT" ["Content-Type"]=> string(31) "application/json; charset=utf-8" ["Transfer-Encoding"]=> string(7) "chunked" ["Connection"]=> string(10) "keep-alive"}

Comment: See the trailing whitespace…?